# Creating a 3D surface plot from two vectors and a matrix

Tags: r, plot, surface, rgl

I have got two vectors and a 2D-matrix, from which I want to create a 3D surface plot. I already have split my data into X and Y (vectors (time "t" and wavelength "w") and Z (matrix; absorbance "NIR" at time and wavelength) with the same number of rows/columns respectively:

```
t = matrix(1:456, ncol= 1)
w = matrix(1350:1650, nrow = 1)
NIR = as.matrix(read.table("NIR_alle_pur.txt", header = TRUE, dec =","))
colnames(NIR) = c(paste0("NIR.", 1350:1650))
dim(NIR)
# [1] 456 301
dput(NIR_example)
structure(c(60771.93, 57230.56, 56235.96, 41617.47, 41709.93, 
57466.6, 59916.97, 63376.4, 41966.73, 41254.34, 65535, 61468.76, 
65535, 41238.03, 42530.97, 56936.03, 65009.4, 65535, 40375.5, 
41021.6, 62757, 65455.44, 63795.6, 41349.6, 41178.2), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("NIR.Spectrum_1350.0000000", "NIR.Spectrum_1351.0000000", 
"NIR.Spectrum_1352.0000000", "NIR.Spectrum_1353.0000000", "NIR.Spectrum_1354.0000000"
)))
```

I tried to insert those into the `rgl.surface` function, but I get the following error message:

*Error in rgl.surface(x, y, z, coords = 1:3) : Bad dimension for rows*

I've also tried to plot them with `plotly`, but my success was equally low.

Can someone give me an input how I can get my spectral data to look like the last ones (multiple surfaces) on [this site](https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/), individually? I'll try the overlay of the surfaces with `plotly`later on!

I am happy for every extra input and information on my level!
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show some sample data using `dput`? From what you write I have the feeling your data is 4D (2D from x, y and 2D from matrix), so what exactly is your "third dimension"?

Comment: Two comments:  you should post a simple example to show the structure of your data.  I suspect the issue is that you've got `Z` transposed from what it should be, but without sample code, I'm not sure.  Secondly, you should use `surface3d` rather than the lower level `rgl.surface`.  It behaves more like other R graphics functions.  Note that the arguments are slightly different, so you may need to modify your code.

Comment: @symbolrush I've got spectral data over time at different wavelength: the vectors x,y are time and wavelength and the matrix z describes the absorbance at a specific time and wavelength. I'll edit my question with data to let you see what I'm working with. I think that I narrowed down my problem to the matrix and that there is a format error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the source code, I'd guess the problem is that you stored your `x` and `y` vectors as matrices.  If they are matrices, they need to be identical in shape to `z`.

As I mentioned in a comment, you should avoid using `rgl.surface` (and the other `rgl.*` functions in most cases), and use `surface3d` instead, or `persp3d` if you want axes.

The `*3d` functions are higher level functions that act more like other R functions, and they will lead to fewer problems in the long run.

You haven't posted any data, so I'll post a completely artificial example.  Let's suppose `z = x^2 + y^2 + a`, where `a` is a different constant for each surface.  Then you can plot it like this:

```
x <- seq(-2, 2, length = 7) 
y <- seq(-3, 3, length = 5)  # I've chosen different ranges 
                             # and lengths just to illustrate.
z <- outer(x, y, function(x, y) x^2 + y^2)

colours <- heat.colors(100)
minval <- min(z)
maxval <- max(z) + 10
col <- colours[(z - minval)/(maxval - minval)*99 + 1]
persp3d(x, y, z, col = col)  # get axes the first time

z <- outer(x, y, function(x, y) x^2 + y^2 + 5)
col <- colours[(z - minval)/(maxval - minval)*99 + 1]
surface3d(x, y, z, col = col)  

z <- outer(x, y, function(x, y) x^2 + y^2 + 10)
col <- colours[(z - minval)/(maxval - minval)*99 + 1]
surface3d(x, y, z, col = col) 

aspect3d(1, 1, 1)  # Make axes all equal
```

That produces this plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your example, I'll try to implement it on my data. Would you be so kind and have a quick look on my edited post too? Thank you very much!

Comment: `t` and `w` are matrices, not vectors.

Comment: Thanks for your help!